# Non monobehaviour classes not working properly

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to make a deck of cards in c# for use in Unity. But when i planned it I didn't think that 'Deck.cs' or 'Card.cs' would need to inherit from Monobehaviour.

I have written 3 classes (one is a Monobehaviour, 'Table.cs'). I thought these would work to make a pack of 52 cards.

I get a null reference exception when I try to access the specific card from the Debug.Log line.

Here are the three classes. (I wonder if I am using the 'new' keyword properly)

(Also Table.cs is the monobehaviour and is attached to a Cube called Table in my game scene. There are no other objects or components in the scene besides the default Light and Camera)

```
 using UnityEngine;

public class Table : MonoBehaviour
{
Deck deck;

private void Start()
{
    deck = new Deck();
    Debug.Log("card 9 = " + deck.cards[9].value);

}
}
```

and

```
public class Deck
{
public Card[] cards;



public Deck()
{
    cards = new Card[52];
    for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++)
    {
        for (int val = 0; val < 14; val++)
        {
            Card c = new Card((Card.Suit)suit, val);
        }
    }
}
}
```

and

```
 public class Card
{
public enum Suit { HEARTS = 0, DIAMONDS = 1, SPADES = 2, CLUBS = 3 };
public Suit suit;
public int value;


public Card(Suit Suit, int Value)
{
    suit = Suit;
    value = Value;
}

}
```

The error i get is this: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Table.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Table.cs:12)

And also I first made Card a struct and that doesn't give me the error, but for some reason all the cards remain as HEARTS and value 0 .

Anybody see what I have done wrong? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what would lead you to believe this has anything to do with `MonoBehaviour` or not. You just never actually put any cards in your deck, so of course your deck is full of `null`s when you try to read cards from it. (Or full of `default(Card)`s when using `struct`, the default being the zero of hearts)

You're missing an assignment to store the card `c` into your `cards` array, like this:

```
public Deck()
{
    cards = new Card[52];

    int index = 0;
    for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++)
    {
        for (int val = 1; val <= 13; val++)
        {
            Card c = new Card((Card.Suit)suit, val);

            cards[index++] = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for finding this. I took a long break from coding so i am making silly mistakes all over the place lol. And @SeanCarey thanks for the help however the capital S in Suit was just so I could avoid doing 'this.suit = suit'. Thanks again for the help fixing this